# Handling icon onClick events with Material-UI and ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get the "name" of the icon button when clicked

I've read about using material UI's  but I keep getting "undefined" from the handler

```
import React from 'react'
import {IconButton} from '@material-ui/core'
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/InfoOutlined'

const App = () => {

    const handleIconClicks = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.name)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <IconButton name="details" onClick={(e) => handleIconClicks(e)}>
                <InfoIcon />
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App
```

handleIconClicks() should return the name of the event.target, instead I get undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could not get the name using the event of the IconButton because its event is `null`.
So you could it using this.

```
    const handleIconClicks = name => () => {
        console.log(name);
    }
... ... ...
    <IconButton name="details" onClick={handleIconClicks('detail')}>
       <InfoIcon />
    </IconButton>
... ... ...
```

Answer (score 7):

`event.target` may refer to the icon in case of `<IconButton />`.

You should be able to safely use `event.currentTarget` to get the button (and `event.currentTarget.name` to get its name).